# In nixos, how to export an environment variable on startup?

Tags: environment-variables, nixos

In ubuntu I could place something like

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

in my `.bashrc` file.

How do I do this in nixos?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The same thing should work in nixos, although variables such as `EDITOR` should probably go in `.profile` instead. `.bashrc` is IIRC only sourced for interactive shells so variables exported there won't be available in programs started from your desktop environment menu.

You could also set `environment.variables.VARIABLE = "VALUE";` in `configuration.nix` but not really appropriate for personal variables such as `EDITOR`. (ofc. if you're the only user it doesn't really matter that much)