# point $NIX_PATH to ~/.nix-defexpr/channels

Tags: environment-variables, nixos, nix

I would like to point `$NIX_PATH` to `~/.nix-defexpr/channels` instead of `~/.nix-defexpr/channels_root` as currently. I don't want to have to type that every time I run `nix-env`. What's the right way of doing that?

Comment: Might be helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377599/in-nixos-how-to-export-an-environment-variable-on-startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply define the variable the way you want it in your `~/.profile`.

Comment: And give up statelessness?

Comment: What statelessness?  You update channels "imperatively" - that's how they're designed, so that by default you install from the latest-updated channel without having to specify e.g. the exact commit hash.

Comment: Yes, but we try to keep the state in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` and not all over the place like in a regular Linux distro. I am hoping to have a tidy solution with which I can make a reproducible recipe. I may be using that to create cloud instances, or sharing configuration with colleagues.

Comment: See e.g. http://nix-cookbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-to-pin-nixpkgs-to-a-specific-commit-branch

Answer (score 0):

I still want to know how to do it via configuration, but imperatively through an expression written in a file I can do

```
$ nix-env -if /this/file.nix -I ~/.nix-defexpr/channels
```

This way I'll be using the user's channels. Without it `~/.nix-defexpr/channels_root` is read instead. Which is what I'm trying to avoid here.